# How can I create a new raster from two different rasters like v.patch does?

Tags: grass-gis, reclassify

I have two rasters with zones and I want a patched product from these two as a new classification like:

```
Zone1 Zone2 Result
12   14    1
15   21    2
15   23    3
17   14    4
54   1     5
etc
```

each unique combination of Zone1 and Zone2 values should give a new item of new classification.
Ideally, should be to get a table of reclassification.
r.patch only covers NaN values, so it doesn't meet the goal.
r.cross does very close thing, but it doesn't preserve old values of course.
I think I could use r.cross, vectorize it and then apply r.univar for each of two rasters, then append results as attributes to vectorized zones.

What approach could be enough here, if I use only grass gis commands?
To say the truth, I need only resulting raster and a reclassifying table like above mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the range of values for your two zones, you could consider to multiply one raster by some "scaling factor" then add them together. i.e.

```
r.mapcalc "result = zone1 + (100 * zone2)"
```

If the number of zones in < 100, then the above will create a new raster with values that are unique for all combinations of the two zone rasters.

The reclass table will be, similarly,

```
(all zone1 values) + 100*(all zone2 values)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try via raster calculator. Create a new raster "raster_new" by reclassifying or resampling (watch resolution and computing area) Zone 1 or 2. Then:

```
if(Zone 1 == 12 && Zone2 == 14,1,'raster_new')
```

The speed it up, set up a shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
r.mapcalc 'raster_new = if(Zone 1 == 12 && Zone2 == 14,1,null())' --o 
r.mapcalc 'raster_new = if(Zone 1 == 15 && Zone 2 == 35,2,'raster_new')' --o
r.mapcalc 'raster_new = if(Zone 1 == 15 && Zone 2 == 23,3,'raster_new')' --o
etc.
```

When done, save as "reclass.sh". Navigate to folder via console, and call script with ./reclass.sh